# Is it possible to change the zlib-flate compression level?

Tags: compression

I use the `zlib-flate` compression utility.

Is it possible to compress at different levels. The man page information is pretty vague.

If not is there an alternative utility that allows you to compress using `zlib` at different levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pigz -z# < FileToCompress > CompressedFile
```

Where `#` is the compression level.

Answer (score 1):

## `zlib-flate`

No, this utility can't do different levels of compression.

## Alternatives

Sadly, I did not find an alternative of `zlib` in which you can set compression level, try:

- [`xz` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xz) - you **can** set compression level
- [`bzip2` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bzip2) - you **can** set compression level
- [`gzip` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) - you **can** set compression level